# Additional resources for debian pre-install script

Tags: debian, dpkg

I am making a debian package that relies on a fairly complex pre-install script (specifically, the script handles the package upgrade, and if an older version is already installed, it is important to run some preparation steps before the old files are replaced with the new ones). The preinst depends on some additional resources, which I would like to include in the package. What I wasn't able to figure out, however, is where to put these resources, and where should the preinst script look for them once the package is being installed?

Answer (score 0):

Because the *preinst* maintainer script is run before the filesystem contents of the package have been unpacked, you cannot rely on anything else except for the contents of the *preinst* contents, or things already unpacked from packages listed in **Pre-Depends** or packages in the essential set.

So your options could be to pack the additional data into the *preinst* script, by inlining it or encoding with *base64* or *uuencode* for example; or package the data into a foo-data package and make foo (the package with the *preinst*) **Pre-Depend** on foo-data. But take into account that **Pre-Depends** are a very heavy-handed dependency relationship which can give the package manager frontends a hard time on system upgrade scenarios.